# python script with selenium on was ec2 instance not finding elements

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver, amazon-linux

So my code works on my local machine where I am able to scrape and get all the needed data.  However, when trying to run it remote on Amazon linux server I have gotten errors like selenium can't find element, selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable with the options shown below.

I have tried messing around with downloading chrome and selenium in certain locations following many guides saying the same thing.

I'm wondering if it is a compatibility issue.
Using Google Chrome 85.0.4183.121
and ChromeDriver 2.37.544315

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size={}x{}'.format(1280, 1024))

chrome_path = '/home/ec2-user/usr/bin/chromedriver'
    #chrome_options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)
```

Any insight would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is your local machine where it works also linux?

Comment: yea, im using a mac

Comment: What kind of linux box? Can up open chrome manually?

Comment: i dont have a linux box.  i can open chrome locally

Comment: The "remote on Amazon linux server" can you open chrome there?

Comment: im not sure.  ive tried "google-chrome &" in the command line, which i think opens it but Ive been trying it headless so im not sure.

Comment: If you are unable to open it manually I would expect the exception about "WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable ". Headless or not.

Comment: after the command google-chrome &?

Comment: Chrome and selenium will not work on a linux environment that does not support a ui.  If you are not able to open chrome with your mouse I would expect the  "WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable " error.

Comment: the code was working on the amazon linux with basic websites so i dont know if that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I needed to run a remote server in order to connect remotely.  Also have to use webdriver.Remote.